# Was my CPU kinda broken?

Tags: monitoring, cpu

Today I've received some message from `mcelog` utility,

```
Processor 3 heated above trip temperature. Throttling enabled.
Please check your system cooling. Performance will be impacted
```

It happens when I build a huge program, I'm not sure if it means something.

Did I broke my CPU in some way? Or was it just a normal message

Comment: Building big things, particular big things with parts that can be done in parallel, is probably the most intense kind of work a computer does.  Unlike, eg. video games, it is not throttled by human interaction or heavily assisted by a GPU.  The only potential bottleneck is disk I/O, and most of the time that is irrelevant.  It is basically set the processor on max and leave it there.  So if you are *overclocking*, that may be much more risky building than it is for other activities.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think so. It just means that the CPU is overheating. And your building of a huge program probably is the cause (I'm assuming that after the build finishes things get back to normal, and if you repeat the build the message appears again).

You might want to check your system cooling (eg. fans, dust), as the message suggests.

Answer (score 4):

CPUs are pretty robust. They are designed to become slower (“throttle”) or stop altogether if they detect that they are overheating. There is pretty much zero risk that you damage your CPU by overheating. The only consequence of this overheat is that your system became slower for a while, as the message indicates.

You should see about cleaning or upgrading your cooling system, not because of a risk of damage, but to maintain your system's performance.

Answer (score 1):

These messages can also be false positives, under very specific conditions: http://tech.ryancox.net/2010/11/diagnosing-throttled-or-slow-systems.html